# How can I add a <fx:root> component as a child in FXML?

Tags: java, javafx, parent-child, fxml

I have a custom component that extends `AnchorPane`, as in:

```
public class CustomAnchorPane extends AnchorPane { }
```

I would like to load this within a `BorderPane`. If I wanted to load a regular `AnchorPane`, I would do it as so: (I removed some lines for brevity)

```xml
<BorderPane fx:id="borderpane" ... fx:controller="main.java.Controller">
    <center>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="anchorpane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
    </center>
 </BorderPane>
```

I understand the `<fx:root>` construct is used for reusable/custom components. I do not understand how to set it as a child of the `BorderPane`, however, as I believe it must be the root of the FXML file. Thus the following throws an error:

```xml
<BorderPane fx:id="borderpane" ... fx:controller="main.java.Controller">
    <center>
       <fx:root fx:id="custom_anchorpane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<fx:root>` only makes sense as the root of a fxml, since this is the only place where the parent object of a object created from the fxml is used, but not defined in the fxml itself.

It only makes `FXMLLoader` use the object passed using `setRoot` instead of creating a an element for this tag itself.

Assuming you've properly implemented your custom `Node`, you can use it the way you'd use any other element:

```xml
<BorderPane fx:id="borderpane" ... fx:controller="main.java.Controller">
    <center>
       <CustomAnchorPane fx:id="custom_anchorpane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Note that this requires a suitable import in the processing instructions at the start of the file and the class needs to provide a `public` constructor taking no parameters.

If you didn't create a custom class yourself, but have a fxml file you want to use in a certain playe, you can also use `fx:include`:

```xml
<BorderPane fx:id="borderpane" ... fx:controller="main.java.Controller">
    <center>
       <fx:include source="custom_anchorpane.fxml"/>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realise you could just import the custom component and use it! That's a lot easier and powerful, thank-you.